# How to modify zeros and poles in a delta-sigma modulator loop?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-filters, analog-to-digital, feedback

In this specific case, I am modeling a delta-sigma analog-to-digital converter with a basic loop in which the output $V$ is fed back with unity gain to be subtracted from the previously sampled input $U$ (discrete time) and this difference is fed to an integrator modeled with the transfer function:

$$G(z) = \frac{z^{-1}}{1- z^{-1}}$$

[image: 1st order block diagram]

Quantization noise is added in form of error $E$ to the output of the integrator, giving the output $V$. It follows:

$$V(z)=\frac{G(z)}{1+G(z)}U(z)+\frac{1}{1+G(z)}E(z)$$

The complete model, however, should be a **third-order system** in which the output $V$ is fed back with unity gain twice more so that it is once subtracted from the sampled input in the **outer loop**, this difference is then integrated and fed to the **next loop**, in which the fed-back output is subtracted again. This new delta enters the second integrator and the same process repeats once more in the **inner loop**, where the quantization error is added as described in the first lines above.
In total there will be **2 identical outer loops and a third inner loop** where the quantization is added. In total there will be **3 integrators** with transfer function $G$.

[image: 3rd order block diagram with gains for poles]
**the minus sign is missing in the second picture for all three summation nodes. it was a mistake. the feedbacks should be indeed negative**

Now I'm interested in the **Noise Transfer Function**: NTF = $V / E$. According to my computations:

[image: procedure for ntf]

NTF *with gain unity in all three feedback paths* (alpha, beta and gamma are 1) should be equal to:

$$\text{NTF}(z)=\frac{V(z)}{E(z)}=\frac{1}{G(z)^3+3G(z)^2+3G(z)+1}$$

It follows:

$$\text{NTF}(z)=\frac{(z-1)^3}{(z-1)^3+3(z-1)^2+3(z-1)+1}$$

From here, I would like to do two things:

- Replace the poles $z1 = 1$, $z2 = 1$ and $z3 = 1$ of the NTF with different values. In order to do so, I simply introduced a gain factor in the feedback path of each of the three loops (alpha, beta and gamma as above). This will add three coefficients in the denominator that I can play with.

However:

- I would also like to replace two of the zeros of the NTF, which are now all equal to 1, with a pair of **complex conjugate zeros**. This should provide "lower noise around the zeros, at the expense of a less effective shaping at $z = 1$, thus increasing the usable frequency range".

If I understand correctly, the numerator $N(z)$ of the NTF should be something like this in the end:

$$N(z)=(z-1)(z-e^{jω})(z-e^{-jω})$$

My question is: how do I achieve this? **What should I add in the model to shift the zeros slightly away from DC?**

Just for information: once I have also obtained a pair of complex conjugate zeros, I should solve an optimization problem to find the optimal position of poles and zeros in the NTF for a determinate quantization noise power. So my humble guess is that ideally I should add something as simple as a gain in the model for the zeros, too, so that can adjust the numerator of the NTF, too, and solve for the optimal zeros within certain boundaries.

Comment: This is a question of substance.

Comment: well, before i really jump into this, since you're saying that this is sigma-delta (or *"delta-sigma"*), does that mean that the output of the quantizer is binary?  That is $$ v[n] = \pm 1 $$ in some given units?  If that is the case, you have an issue about the *"gain of the quantizer"* or the *"gain of the comparator"* and that gain is not necessarily equal to $1$.  And there is necessarily a delay of one sample upon feedback.  There must be a $z^{-1}$ in the feedback path.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thank you for your interest in the question. In our exercise the assumption is exactly that of a 1-bit quantizer, however we're not simulating any conversion to and from binary, the quantizer is represented by an approximating function with a specific step size. I hope that makes sense. The delay you're taking about is included in the filter transfer function G, I think.

Comment: Well, Andrea, your professor might be missing something.  There is a paper by John Paulos from 1986 where this gain of the comparator is discussed.  I have some math for it.  I also have a MATLAB file for demonstration.  Do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

i dunno, i might have posted this before.  but here is a 2nd-order sigma-delta quantizer that operates **not** as an oversampled rate.  so you can hear the quantization noise, but you can also hear the music beneath it.  and the output is binary: $y[n] = \pm A$.

your professor is mistaken if he/she thinks they can model this *without* the $z^{-1}$ in the feedback path nor leave out the gain of the comparator.

```
%
%
%
%
%
%
%   simulated 1 bit sigma-delta converter:
%
%
%            x(n)-y(n-1)    w(n)                v(n)                 ( mean(y^2) = A^2 )
%
%   x ---->(+)--->[1/(z-1)]--->(+)--->[1/(z-1)]--->[Quantizer]----.---> y = +/- A = quantized value
%           ^                   ^                                 |
%           |                   |                                 |
%           |                   '----[-fbg]<----.                 |
%           |                                   |                 |
%           '------[-1]<------------------------'------[1/z]<-----'
%
%
%
%
%
%   "linearized" model:
%                                                          .---- q = quantization noise  ( mean(q) = 0 )
%                                                          |
%                                                          |
%            x - y/z        w                   v          |         ( mean(y^2) = G^2*mean(v^2) + mean(q^2) )
%                                                          v
%   x ---->(+)--->[1/(z-1)]--->(+)--->[1/(z-1)]--->[G]--->(+)-----.---> y = G*v + q
%           ^                   ^                                 |
%           |                   |                                 |
%           |                   '----[-fbg]<----.                 |
%           |                                   |                 |
%           '------[-1]<------------------------'------[1/z]<-----'
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%           W = 1/(z-1)*(X - Y/z)
%
%
%           V = 1/(z-1)*(W - fbg*Y/z) 
%
%             = (X - Y/z - fbg*Y*(z-1)/z)/(z-1)^2
%
%             = (X*z - Y*(1+fbg*(z-1))) / (z*(z-1)^2)
%
%
%           Y = G*V + Q = G*(X*z - Y*(1+fbg*(z-1)))/(z*(z-1)^2) + Q
%
%             = G*X/(z-1)^2 - G*Y*(1+fbg*(z-1))/(z*(z-1)^2) + Q
%
%
%           Y + G*Y*(1-fbg + fbg*z)/(z*(z-1)^2) = G*X/(z-1)^2 + Q
%
%
%           Y = (G*X/(z-1)^2 + Q)/(1 + G*(1-fbg + fbg*z)/(z*(z-1)^2))
%
%             = (G*X/(z-1)^2 + Q)*(z*(z-1)^2)/((z*(z-1)^2) + G*(1-fbg + fbg*z))
%
%             = z*(G*X + Q*(z-1)^2)/(z^3 - 2*z^2 + (G*fbg+1)*z + G*(1-fbg))
%
%             = z*(G*X + Q*(z-1)^2)/(z*(z-1)^2 + G*fbg*z + G*(1-fbga))
%
%
%    as z -> 1  (DC)
%
%           Y  ->  z*X/(fbg*z + (1-fbg)) =  X/(fbg + (1-fbg)/z)  -->  X
%
%



if ~exist('mean_vv', 'var')
    linearized_model = 0                % run this with 0 the first time to define G and mean(q^2)
end

if ~exist('A', 'var')
    A = 1.0                             % comparator output magnitude
end

if ~exist('fbg', 'var')
    fbg = 2.0                           % feedback gain to internal integrator
end

%
%   if there is an input soundfile specified, use it.  else, create a sin wave
%


if exist('inputFile', 'var')

    [inputBuffer, Fs] = audioread(inputFile);

    fileSize = length(inputBuffer);

    numSamples = 2.^(ceil(log2(fileSize(1))));  % round up to nearest power of 2

    x = zeros(numSamples, 1);                   % zero pad if necessary

    x(1:fileSize) = inputBuffer(:,1);           % if multi-channel, use left channel only

    clear inputBuffer;                          % free this memory
    clear fileSize;

    t = linspace(0.0, (numSamples-1)/Fs, numSamples);   % time

else

    if ~exist('numSamples', 'var')
        numSamples = 65536                              % number of samples in simulation
    end

    if ~exist('Fs', 'var')
        Fs = 44100                                      % (oversampled) sample rate
    end

    if ~exist('f0', 'var')
        f0 = 261.6255653                                % input freq (middle C)
    end

    if ~exist('Amplitude', 'var')
        Amplitude = 0.25                                % input amplitude
    end

    t = linspace(0.0, (numSamples-1)/Fs, numSamples);   % time
    x = Amplitude*cos(2*pi*f0*t);                       % the input

end

sound(x, Fs);                                   % listen to input sound
pause;

y = zeros(1, numSamples);                       % the output (created and initialized for speed later) 

if linearized_model
                                                % artificial quantization noise for linearized model
                                                % mean(q) = 0, var(q) = mean(q^2) = mean(y^2) - G^2*mean(v^2)
                                                % does not have to be uniform or triangle p.d.f.
    q = sqrt(6.0*(A^2 - G^2*mean_vv))*( rand(1, numSamples) - rand(1, numSamples) );
else
    q = zeros(1, numSamples);
end

sum_yv = 0.0;
sum_vv = 0.0;

w = 0;
v = 0;
for n = 1:numSamples

    if linearized_model

        y(n) = G*v + q(n);                      % here the comparator is modelled as a little gain with additive noise

    else

        if (v >= 0)                             % the comparator
            y(n) = +A;
        else
            y(n) = -A;
        end

        q(n) = y(n) - (sum_vv+1e-20)/(sum_yv+1e-20)*v;

    end

    sum_yv = sum_yv + y(n)*v;                   % collect some statistics on v
    sum_vv = sum_vv +    v*v;

    v = v + w  - fbg*y(n);                      % second integrator
    w = w + x(n) - y(n);                        % first integrator

end

if ~linearized_model                            % don't recalculate this if using the linearized model
    mean_yv = sum_yv/numSamples;
    mean_vv = sum_vv/numSamples;
    G = mean_yv/mean_vv;                        % the apparent comparator gain (assuming stationary input)
end

%
%
%
%     Y = ((G*z)*X + (z^3 - 2*z^2 + z)*Q) / (z^3 - 2*z^2 + (G*a+1)*z + G*(1-a))
%
%
%
Hx = freqz([0  0 G 0], [1 -2 G*fbg+1 G*(1-fbg)], numSamples/2);
Hq = freqz([1 -2 1 0], [1 -2 G*fbg+1 G*(1-fbg)], numSamples/2);



plot(t, y, 'b');
sound(y, Fs);                                   % this could sound pretty bad
pause;


Y = fft(fftshift(y .* kaiser(numSamples, 5.0)'));
Q = fft(fftshift(q .* kaiser(numSamples, 5.0)'));

f = linspace(0.0, (numSamples/2-1)/numSamples*Fs, numSamples/2);

plot(f, 20*log10(abs(Y(1:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'b');
hold on;
plot(f, 20*log10(abs(Q(1:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'r');
plot(f, 20*log10(abs(Hq) + 1e-10), 'g');
axis([0 Fs/2 -50 100]);
hold off;
pause;

semilogx(f(2:numSamples/2), 20*log10(abs(Y(2:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'b');
hold on;
semilogx(f(2:numSamples/2), 20*log10(abs(Q(2:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'r');
semilogx(f(2:numSamples/2), 20*log10(abs(Hq(2:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'g');
axis([Fs/numSamples Fs/2 -50 100]);
hold off;
pause;


semilogx(f(2:numSamples/2), 20*log10(abs(Y(2:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'b');
hold on;
semilogx(f(2:numSamples/2), 20*log10(abs(Hq(2:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'r');
semilogx(f(2:numSamples/2), 20*log10(abs(Hx(2:numSamples/2)) + 1e-10), 'g');
axis([Fs/numSamples Fs/2 -50 110]);
hold off;
```